# Custom viewpager tabs with custom view, multiple fragment and layouts

Tags: android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android

I want to make a viewpager which is just like latest facebook application.

[image: facebook latest application snap]

and the problem is with tabs.

however i tried to make it, but i need icons with text in tabs and multiple fragments and layouts associated with it.

two issue occurred when i tried to develop.
 1. I compromised with my UI, and tried putting static icons in it, but they don't change on selection and they don't even have badge like in facebook application. 
 2. when i put that code in my application which i have developed in demo app, it shows error and after researching i found that my application don't have an actionbar. so it was giving error after calling `getActionBar`.

please someone can provide any example or link to that which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official solution: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Or try this awsome lib: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: 1. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html | imported project and project have errors, even after adding support library

2.https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip | Does it provide to have an icon in tab? and does the icon changes when it is selected? like in facebook application.

i have tried both of them.

Comment: 1. You just add the latest android-support-v4.jar lib, that will clean all errors. 2. PagerSlidingTabStrip provide TEXT and ICON tab, but no icon-with-text tab by default, but you can modify a few code to implement this.